# Rails: practical considerations of parallel class names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

Relatively new to Rails and trying to suss out the implications of using parallel classnames under separate namespaces. For example:

```
gateways/
    payment.rb      # abstract
    subscription.rb # abstract
    stripe/
        payment.rb
        subscription.rb
    paypal/
        payment.rb
        subscription.rb
```

Are there any pitfalls to using such a scheme? Specifically, will the overlapping names lead to any confusing behavior from Rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will create no confusing behaviour, provided you namespace your classes properly. For example,

```
gateways/
    payment.rb           # Gateway::Base::Payment
    subscription.rb      # Gateway::Base::Subscription
    stripe/
        payment.rb       # Gateway::Stripe::Payment
        subscription.rb  # Gateway::Stripe::Subscription
    paypal/
        payment.rb       # Gateway::Paypal::Payment
        subscription.rb  # Gateway::Paypal::Subscription
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! The Base namespace makes a lot of sense.